# PHP injections in an email to add a header?

Tags: php, email, header, sql-injection, code-injection

The exchange server I am working with is about 10 years old and I have no control over any of its settings. It strips the MIME header on every email's body and I need that MIME header so I was thinking if its possible to put echo statements or some html statements kind of like SQL injections in the input that would add the MIME header before the body. Is this possible?

Comment: I think it depends on the email client.

Comment: im sending email from MS outlook- exchange server

Comment: it doesn't matter what is sending the email, what matters is what's receiving it. It depending on how the email client pulls up the email and renders it to the browser. For example CGI scripts will not work in almost all cases, but client side code like javascript may work. But it depends on what's reading the email, and how it is read.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing can cause the behaviour that you are asking. The MIME header has to be set prior to sending the email.

Even if you have some kind of javascript that injects the MIME into the email header, it would do so after the email is loaded by the client. This would not cause the client to understand the MIME header.